# How to write file size validation logic in React & Typescript

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript

I am working with React & Typescript and want to add validation logic when uploading image files.
It accepts up to 2 images and 10 Megabyte (sum of 2 images) is the maximum size that user can upload.

I currently have below code to validate the above logic but I am confused if my unit comparison is correct.

```
    const onFileUpload = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        const selectableMaxFileSize = 1024 * 1024 * 10 // 10 Megabyte
        let initialFileSize: number = 0

        if (e.target.files) {
         for (let i = 0; i < e.target.files.length; i++) {
                const file = e.target.files[i]
                initialFileSize += file.size
            }
        if (initialFileSize > selectableMaxFileSize) {
            setHasModal(true)
            e.target.value = ''
            return
        }
```

Also I noticed I can simply access to file size by `e.target.size`, then compare with `selectableMaxFileSize` - does this work as well?

Comment: Does this work as well? why dont u try it and let us know the result?

Comment: the returned number (unit) from `e.target.size` and `file.size` is different so I am confused what unit type is associated with each one.

Comment: The `.size` attribute of and `HTMLInputElement` is the size of the control. [REF](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attributes)

Comment: `file.size` is in bytes (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/size), so your comparison is correct (assuming by "megabyte" you actually mean "mebibyte"). `e.target.size` returns the size attribute of the input (see [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement))